# Optimization Algorithm for Pipe Joining (Opposite of Cutting Stock Algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am presented with a problem where I have to connect two points using pipes. I have an inventory of pipes with different lengths and I need to optimize the selection of the pipes to minimize the wasted pipes (more than the target) and to minimize joints between pipes.

I searched for algorithms for this problem and found the cutting stock algorithm which is basically the opposite of what I need to do. Are there any algorithms that deal with this type of problems? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What's the solution for `points = [0, 5]; pipes = [7, 2]`? if we choose 7, we get 0 joints but 2 over the length required; and if we choose 3 * 2, we get 2 joints but only 1 over the length required. Clearly, we can invent more arbitrary examples with different challenges to two objectives.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting insight. To determine which option is best, we need a cost function. Let's say each joint will cost the same as 0.5 units of pipe. So if the cut section is less than 0.5, it is considered waste. If it is more, we can reuse it and it is not wasted. So in your example, using the 7-pipe will be the better solution.

Comment: Hello, please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "opposite" of the cutting stock problem is the bin packing problem (BPP) - though mathematically they are essentially the same. Also, in your case, you are allowed to exceed the capacity of the bin. The BPP can be formulated as a mixed integer linear program (MILP) and solved by a MILP solver like CBC, CPLEX, Gurobi, etc. There are also various heuristics available, which will find at least a good solution.

Note that considering offcuts longer than 0.5 as not waste will likely lead to an accumulation of short pieces. That will increase the number of joins, and hence cost, later. i.e. a short-term optimal solution may not be optimal in the long term.